# If only part of a word that is in my list is inputted, my code checks it as true and that the partial word is in the list

Tags: python, list

I just started coding with Python, here is my code.

```
pOneCards = ["Jack S", "Queen H", "5 C", "2 S"]
dropCard = input()
dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
while dropCardCapital not in str(pOneCards):
    dropCard = input()
    dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
if dropCardCapital in str(pOneCards):
        print("You dropped " + dropCardCapital)
```

When the user inputs the letter J here or like Que the code will count it as that it is inside the list and break the while loop.

I want it to only count it true when the whole entire word is put in.

Comment: Please explain what is the whole entire word. Is `Jack` an entire word or not?

Answer (score 3):

you shouldn't cast `pOneCards` to `str`,

try this please:

```py
pOneCards = ["Jack S", "Queen H", "5 C", "2 S"]
dropCard = input()
dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
while dropCardCapital not in str(pOneCards):
    dropCard = input()
    dropCardCapital = dropCard.title()
if dropCardCapital in pOneCards:
        print("You dropped " + dropCardCapital)
```

the value of `str(pOneCards)` is `"['Jack S', 'Queen H', '5 C', '2 S']"`, which is of type string, and of course `Que` is a substring of it.

if you don't `str` it, then `pOneCards` is a list of strings, and `in` checks whether the string `dropCardCapital` is one of the strings in the list (a complete match of course)